# How to create custom component that takes in (and passes) down all possible TextField arguments?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I currently have following custom component that wraps and styles a default `TextField` from swift ui. I came across an issue where I now need to re-use this where `@Binding` is no longer just String, but rather, can be a number like int or double, thus underlying `TextField` needs to change and take in `TextField(value: ..., formatter: ...)` instead of just `text`.

I can turn all of the modifiers into a custom modifier and apply it to relevant text fields to apply the styling, but am wondering if there is a solution where I can keep this as a custom component and instead allow `TextInputSmall` to take in and pass down all possible permutations of TextField arguments, for example

`TextInputSmall("", text: $someString)` and `TextInputSmall("", value: $someNumber, formatter: .number)`

```
struct TextInputSmall: View {
  // Public Variables
  var accentColor = Color._orange
  @Binding var text: String
  
  // Private Variables
  @FocusState private var focused: Bool
  
  // Body
  var body: some View {
    TextField(
      "",
      text: $text
    )
    .font(...)
    .foregroundStyle(...)
    .accentColor(...)
    .focused($focused)
    .submitLabel(.done)
    .frame(...)
    .padding(...)
    .background(...)
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add more initialisers to `TextInputSmall`? What part of this are you having trouble with? What errors did you get when you tried doing this?

Comment: @Sweeper I haven't used custom initializers within SwiftUI component as of yet, any chance you could provide an example as an answer. I'll try to look this up as well meanwhile.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do that. That said, IMO the "correct" solution as you said, is a `ViewModifier`.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried the initializer approach, but one bit I'm struggling with is having `text` argument still in TextField, in scenario with value and formatter it needs to be nil or empty string, but those cases error as only valid value for this arg is a Binding<String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically "steal" the declarations of `TextField` and its initialisers and put them into your own code. Add a `TextField` property in your wrapper, and in each initialiser, initialise that property by creating a `TextField` using the corresponding initialiser.

Here is an example for `init(_:text:)` and `init(_:value:format)`:

```
struct CustomTextField<Label: View>: View {
    let textField: TextField<Label>
    
    init(_ title: LocalizedStringKey, text: Binding<String>) where Label == Text {
        textField = TextField(title, text: text)
    }
    
    init<F>(_ title: LocalizedStringKey, value: Binding<F.FormatInput>, format: F)
        where F: ParseableFormatStyle, F.FormatOutput == String, Label == Text {
        textField = TextField(title, value: value, format: format)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        textField
            .padding(10)
            // ...add your own styling...
    }
}
```

That said, this is quite tedious if you want to have *all* the combinations of `TextField.init`. IMO, using a `ViewModifier` like you suggested is the more idiomatic and correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the better solution would be to use a ViewModifier.

But, you need to be clear what the modifier is responsible for and for what not.

You could think to implement it like:

```
struct MyModifier<L: View>: ViewModifier {
    
    let accentColor: Color
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.body)
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            .accentColor(.red)
            // .focused($focused)
            // .submitLabel(.done)
            // .frame(...)
            // .padding()
            .background(.green)
    }
}
```

I commented out those properties, which should *not* go into this modifier. This has a clear reason. When you look closer, the modifier only mutates "style" properties, but no "layout" properties.

It also does not set the focus, which is completely orthogonal what a style modifier should do.

So, when designing a modifier, try to separate the concepts. Don't mix up style with layout, and don't handle state properties (like focus) in the modifier.

Regarding the focus, you should provide a FocusState in a *parent* view where it has several views having a focus. Putting it into a custom view, which wraps a *single* TextField makes no sense.

Once you have the modifier, you don't need the custom view, just apply the modifier to any view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "Hello, world!"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .modifier(MyModifier(accentColor: .red))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```